# Text editor widget which supports syntax highlight, links and online spell checking

Tags: java, widget, text-editor

I'm looking for a embeddable text editor widget/component which supports syntax highlight, links and online spell checking (like in modern web browsers and word processors, i.e. without having to click on "Spell Check" buttons).

My app is using Java and SWT, so I can use any Java based text editor or HTML JavaScript ones (by using the `Browser` widget which does support WebKit). It's also possible to embed Swing-based editors.

The solution should run at least on the three major platforms (Win, Mac, Linux).

Comment: I'm looking for an editor component/widget, not a standalone editor that can edit Java code.

Answer (score 2):

It's all there!

- [JSyntaxPane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/) is an EditorKit for [JEditorPane (Swing)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html), i.e. you can simply plug it in to an existing EditorPane.
- [Jazzy Swing](http://freecode.com/projects/jazzy) is a SpellChecker library for Swing which can be plugged in independently from JSyntaxPane, i.e. you can use them together and with standard widgets (like JEditorPane).
- JEditorPane is already capable of displaying links. There is an example [over here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html) on how to use Hyperlinks with a JEditorPane.

Of course this solution is targetting primarily Swing Applications, but as you said Swing was no problem for you, this seems like viable options.

Answer (score 1):

http://jintilla.sourceforge.net/ is a Java SWT and AWT port of [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/)

The project looks stale but it might be a good starting point.

Comment: But that's not embeddable into a Java application.

Comment: Sorry, my bad; the Java port lives over here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jintilla/ / http://jintilla.sourceforge.net/ … and looks a bit stale, actually, but might do the job?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a cross platform [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/). Though I don't see any documentation that states it has a spell check feature. **Update** There is a [spell check plugin for jEdit](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?SpellCheck).

Emacs, if you learn it's keyboard shortcuts it's truly amazing though getting it working with Java takes a bit of tinkering (if you don't want to use the command line and instead want to use a keyboard shortcut to compile and run java applications). It has versions for each OS you mentioned.

**Windows Only**

[TextPad](http://www.textpad.com) used to be the standard for text editors that support java and works with java immediately after installation it also has various [dictionaries](http://www.textpad.com/download/lexicons.html) to suite your need. The application is extremely mature and doesn't change much any more for this reason.

On Windows machine, I would probably go with TextPad, personally I now use [Programmers Notepad 2](http://www.pnotepad.org/) however it does not support a spell checker and I don't really thinks it's better than TextPad by any measure.

Comment: jEdit has a text spelling plugin but it's offline. Emacs isn't embeddable.

Comment: Sorry, seems to have missed your embeddable requirement. FYI, we have an app in which we embedded a text editor, we just implemented Syntax Highlighting, auto indenting and even auto-complete by ourselves, it's not a lot of work and you can find code to do most of it online. Sure it'll be buggy, but probably faster than anything you can embed.